# Angular Reactive Forms - proper annotation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form in an angular component:

```
this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
  agencyName: ['', [Validators.required],
  taxId: ['', [Validators.required],
  address: ['', Validators.required],
  city: ['', Validators.required],
  state: ['', Validators.required],
  zip: ['', Validators.required],
  county: ['', Validators.required],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  mobile: ['', Validators.required],
  phone: [''],
});
```

What is the correct way to assign a control in this form to a variable?

```
this.control = this.signUpForm.controls.state;
```

or

```
this.control = this.signUpForm.controls.['state'];
```

In Angular 14 I am getting syntax error highlighting for the first annotation, while in previous versions it has worked.

Comment: `this.signUpForm.get('state')` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.control = this.signUpForm..get('state')
```

- OR we can define a function :

  ```
      get state() {

    return this.signUpForm.get('state');
  }
  ```

you can also get the value in the HTML so you can subscribe to it  :

```
this.signUpForm.get('state').valueChanges.subscribe(
      value => console.log(value)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this to get your each form control**

```
get agencyName(){
    return this.signUpForm.get('agencyName');
}
```